# how to find if a background-color of pseudo::selection css value is inherited in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to get the background-color of an element of the style css. How do i find this using get. CssValue with selenium webdriver. Java

```
 ::selection {
     background-color: #cce2ff;
     color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
    }
```

my current code to find the element

```
public void getCalendarInfo(){
    List<WebElement> calendarElements = driver.findElements(CalendarTableXPath);

      for(int i =0; i< calendarElements.size(); i++){
      System.out.println(calendarElements.get(i).getText().toString());
      System.out.println(calendarElements.get(i).getCssValue(" what do i enter here 
      ").toString());

     }
 }
```

UPDATE: So i was able to use js executor...However i noticed now that every div contains this...But the current div that is the current date inherits it...any way to validate that it is inherited instead?

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0],'.rbc-date-cell.rbc-now').getPropertyValue('font-weight');", calendarElements.get(i)).toString();
```

Comment: This css is from pseudo::selection element in the css style

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get color from element use:

```
element.getCssValue("color");
```

and there is no need to do `toString()` because both `getText()` and `getCssValue("color")` returns String

Comment: Yes, I am able to get the color..However the element inherits another color from its styles pseudo ::selection css section.  Is there a way to validate whether it is inherited? all the elements have the same color from this section of css...except on current date  div it is actually inheriting the color